# excel if formula returning a value of false rather than a numerical value

Tags: excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet where I compile numbers, I have been using this same spreadsheet for over a year now. I designed all the formulas and everything has been working fine. This morning when I opened up the spreadsheet one of the formulas is returning a value of false which is screwing up all my other formulas since they rely on that cell. the formulas is =IF('DME Works invoice detail'!$K:$K>0,COUNT('DME Works invoice detail'!$K:$K)) very basic formula. Now the weird part about it is that if I move the formula to another cell it works fine. if I shift cells down it works fine. What else could be causing this? I am sure it is something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find that `'DME Works invoice detail'!$K:$K` is not greater than 0.

Looking at the formula I think it should be `=IF(COUNT('DME Works invoice detail'!$K:$K)>0,COUNT('DME Works invoice detail'!$K:$K))`.

The `IF` function has three parts - `IF(condition,result if condition true,result if condition false)`
You have no `result if false` part so it's returning the value FALSE.

Comment: That works and it makes since. It has been working up until today though, which I found very odd. I would give you the up mark but I don't have enough reputation :(